# Variation of Attack besides Center Control and Flanking

Tags: analysis

Does in official games, had happened when a player didn't concentrate his attack to center or by flanking??

In this case, my possible attack is used side of board when opponent had castling the king to certain side.

I've this method in my childhood, but seldom to see it in chess engine except versus weak opponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attacking isn't necessarily generalized to areas of the board. For example, I can attack your queen with my pawn, and this isn't a localized concept. Your question seems to imply that you're asking about attacks on the opposing king as you specify attacking the side of the board where your opponent has castled. There exist far more aggressive strategies than controlling the center or flanking out the opponent. Consider tactics, square and file control, general initiative, and development as alternatives.

Comment: +1. yep.. you're right.. I am planning to attacking the king. It seems hard to find some movement like that since you said, `There exist far more aggressive strategies ...`